# WPF: Use a different template depending on size and number of items

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles

I'm trying to work out how I can alter the template depending on the size and number of items. This is very similar to the ribbon which dynamically changes depending on the size, or Windows 7 thumbnail of programs.

In this case, it's an ItemTemplate of a ListBox and I want to reduce the size of the image or not display it, rather than having scroll bars.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />                        
                <Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could set a style on the ListBox, which switches ItemTemplate based on the number of items.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <local:SizeConverter x:Key="SizeConverter"/>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="SmallTemplate"></DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="MediumTemplate"></DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="LargeTemplate"></DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.Resources>
    <ListBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ListBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Items.Count, Converter={StaticResource SizeConverter}}" Value="Small">
                    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" Value="{StaticResource SmallTemplate}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Items.Count, Converter={StaticResource SizeConverter}}" Value="Medium">
                    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" Value="{StaticResource MediumTemplate}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Items.Count, Converter={StaticResource SizeConverter}}" Value="Large">
                    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" Value="{StaticResource LargeTemplate}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.Style>            
</ListBox>
```

The SizeConverter would be an IValueConverter which returns a size category based on the incoming count, the convert method could be something like this:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    int count = (int)value;
    if (count < 4) return "Large";
    if (count < 12) return "Medium";            
    return "Small";
}
```

Comment: Thanks - have bound the ListBox.ItemTemplate to an IMultiValueConverter which takes the available size and number of items and returns the appropriate resource.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to use the [DataTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector.aspx) functionality in WPF:

From the link:

> Typically, you create a
>   DataTemplateSelector when you have
>   more than one DataTemplate for the
>   same type of objects and you want to
>   supply your own logic to choose a
>   DataTemplate to apply based on the
>   properties of each data object. Note
>   that if you have objects of different
>   types you can set the DataType
>   property on the DataTemplate. If you
>   do that then there is no need to
>   create a DataTemplateSelector.
>   Furthermore, if you have objects of
>   the same type but with different
>   properties, you can also consider
>   using a DataTrigger or a data
>   converter. For more information, see
>   Data Templating Overview.

Or alternatively, as mentioned above, a [DataTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatrigger.aspx) may be of use.

Comment: A DataTemplateSelector is meant to switch based on an individual item, it is, or should be, independent of other the items: If an item is added to the collection, will the templateselector be called for all of the existing items as well? Will all templates refresh? I'm not sure, but i don't think so.

Comment: Good point - a data trigger to a suitable property on the parent control might be the way forward then.