# Design breakpoint to show different item template in listView

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2015, windows-10

I have a listView and want to use different itemTemplate if depending on screen size, I have try visual state manager but its not working for me.

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup>
                <VisualState x:Name="wideState">
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="500"/>
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="narrowState">
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowHeight="0"/>
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Target="hubSectionGrid.Width" Value="320"/>
                        <Setter Target="NowAndNextListView.ItemTemplate" Value="ProgramListItemNarrow"/>
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

Any suggestions to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

This could work from you, taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570317/wpf-use-a-different-template-depending-on-size-and-number-of-items)

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <local:SizeConverter x:Key="SizeConverter"/>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="SmallTemplate"></DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="MediumTemplate"></DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="LargeTemplate"></DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.Resources>
    <ListBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ListBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Items.Count, Converter={StaticResource SizeConverter}}" Value="Small">
                    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" Value="{StaticResource SmallTemplate}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Items.Count, Converter={StaticResource SizeConverter}}" Value="Medium">
                    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" Value="{StaticResource MediumTemplate}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Items.Count, Converter={StaticResource SizeConverter}}" Value="Large">
                    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" Value="{StaticResource LargeTemplate}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.Style>
```

Comment: I can see Style.Triggers when using listView

Comment: Have you tried to create an ItemTemplate Selector? Look at here: http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2014/04/23/xaml-listview-styling-items-based-on-data-windows-8-1-xaml.aspx